# Perfect security definitions

Tags: encryption, one-time-pad, security-definition

In my notes, there are 2 definitions of perfect security:

> 1. "For $M \in \{0,1\}^m$, define the distribution $D_M$ on strings as follows: to choose a random member of $D_M$, choose a random $K \in \{0,1\}^n$ and output $Enc(M,K)$.  Then $Enc,Dec$ is *perfectly secure* if $D_M$ is exactly the same for every $M$.  That is, for every $\alpha \in \{0,1\}^*$, the probability of $\alpha$ according to $D_M$ is independent of $M$.
> 2. For every two messages, no function can tell which one has been encrypted.  That is, $Enc,Dec$ is *perfectly secure* if for every $M_0,M_1 \in \{0,1\}^m$ and for every $f: \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}$, the following holds: consider the experiment where $b$ is randomly chosen from $\{0,1\}$ and $K$ is randomly chosen from $\{0,1\}^n$; then the probability that $f(Enc(M_b,K)) = b$ is equal to $1/2$."

I have two questions:

1. Could someone clarify the definition of $D_M$ (the distribution of strings?). I'm not sure I get what is meant by the "distribution of strings" and how it differs from $M$
2. If $M_0$, and $M_1$ are any two $m$-bit messages, how is it possible that their encryption be equal $b$? Wouldn't the number of bits in the encrypted message be $m$? if that number is for example 10 then how does $P \left ( f( \mathrm{Enc} (M_b, K)) = b \right ) = 0.5$?

Comment: I have typesetted your post to make it more readable - you can do it too by using LaTeX in between dollar signs. Feel free to edit your post if I accidentally changed the meaning of something.

Comment: Your formulas don't look like a definition of perfect security, but like a definition of the one-time-pad, one scheme known to provide perfect security.

Comment: I went a little further and transcribed the linked image. I also deleted the one time pad definition to which @Paŭlo's comment (presumably) refers to, since it didn't really seem relevant to the actual question.

Answer (score 2):

> If M0, and M1 are any 2 m-bit messages, how is it possible that their encryption be equal b?

The definition does not say that their encryption is equal *b*. It says that the function *f* outputs *b*. This function is often called *distinguisher* (or attacker) and he should not be able to distinguish which message *M0* or *M1* was encrypted. In other words there exists no distinguisher who can distinguish which message was encrypted better than with probability of guessing (0.5).

Answer (score 2):

In the first definition, $D_M$ is a [probability distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution).  As the Wikipedia page notes, there are various ways to specify a probability distribution; one of them, which is what's used here, is to specify how to sample a random variable distributed according to that distribution.

Specifically, what the definition is saying is that $D_M$ is the distribution of ciphertexts obtained by encrypting the message $M$ with a randomly chosen key $K$.
In other words, to sample a random variable $X$ distributed according to the distribution $D_M$, you take the message $M$, pick a random key $K$ from the keyspace and let $X = Enc(M,K)$.

(To be specific, the key $K$ should presumably be chosen [uniformly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29) from the set of $n$-bit keys $\{0,1\}^n$, although the definition doesn't explicitly say so.  It's a common convention in cryptography that random variables chosen from a finite set are assumed to be uniformly distributed unless stated otherwise.)

The definition then says that the encryption is perfectly secure if and only if $D_{M_0} = D_{M_1}$ for any two messages $M_0$ and $M_1$ — that is, if, for any given messages $M_0$ and $M_1$, any given ciphertext $C$ and a random key $K$, the probability that $Enc(M_0,K) = C$ equals the probability that $Enc(M_1,K) = C$.

---

In the second definition, the notation $f:\{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}$ means that $f$ is a function from the set $\{0,1\}^*$ of arbitrary bitstrings to the set $\{0,1\}$ of single bits.  That is, $f$ takes a bitstring as input and outputs a single bit.

We can think of the input of $f$ as an encrypted message, and the output of $f$ as a guess about which of $M_0$ or $M_1$ is the plaintext corresponding to the input.  The definition then says that, if (and only if) our encryption system is perfectly secure, then for *any* pair of messages $M_0$ and $M_1$ and *any* distinguisher $f$, if we take a random message $M$ chosen from the given pair of messages, and encrypt it with a random key $K$ to get a ciphertext $C = Enc(M,K)$, then the guess $f(C)$ has no more (and no less) than a 50% change of being correct.